# Seleniumが突然使えなくなり再度インストールしようとするとエラーがでる

Tags: python, selenium

Seleniumが突然使えなくなりました

再度pipを使いインストールしようとすると以下のようなエラーがでます

同じような事例の方,もしくは解決法を知っているかたがいらっしゃいましたらご教授いただければ幸いです.

```
Collecting selenium
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/1f/6c2204b9ae14eddab615c5e2ee4956c65ed533e0a9986c23eabd801ae849/selenium-3.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: selenium
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

このエラーは、アクセス権がないため発生するもので、Linuxで単に以下のようにコマンドを打つたものと思われます。

```
pip install selenium
```

それだと、OSに付属の Python 2.7にパッケージをインストールしようとします。OSに付属の Python 2.7にインストールしたいのであれば、管理者権限が必要になります。OSに付属の Python は、ユーザーが触るべきものではありません。エラーが出ることで間違いを防いでくれています。

Linuxの場合は、仮想環境を作って、仮想環境を起動してから pip を使いましょう。

```
source bin/activate
pip install selenium
```

Seleniumが突然使えなくなったというのも仮想環境に入るのを忘れたためではないでしょうか。

Comment: Yasuhiro Niji様。ご回答ありがとうございます。OSはMacなのですが、その場合はどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: Macの場合はどういう環境にしているかによって変わってくるので、結構ややこしいです。Seleniumを使っているプログラムはpython2かpython3か、仮想環境で動かしているのかどうか、PATHの設定をどうしているかを質問に書くといいと思います。

Comment: 突然使えなくなくなったという場合は、PATHの設定が変更されてしまった場合が多いと思います。python, pipではなくてpython3, pip3を使うと動く可能性がかなりあります。